# Putting values inside linked list header while using fgets()

Tags: c, linked-list

I've been working on an assignment where we are given a .ssv file that contains bank accounts in the first column and transactions in the second (20 is adding $20 and -20 is taking away $20), and are asked to create a linked list of the accounts using multiple c file.

There are three in question: main.c (opens the ssv and goes line by line), ssv.c (contains a function for parsing out the data from the fgets() string) and linked.c (creates the linked list and updates the account balances by matching the account number and adding the transaction). They are required to remain separate and cannot be made into .h files.

As my code stands currently, nothing it getting put into my linked list header as it would get overwritten every iteration of the while(fgets()) if i just had it write straight to the header. Therefore, I'm looking for some way to have the first line get written to the header and then the loop continues like normal, adding new accounts or updating transactions in current ones. I also noticed that it doesn't seem to be updating the transaction amounts, as it just lists account 10 as having no money. Any input anywhere would be appreciated.

./bank Output:

```
ctonne2, ~/Projects/COMP206/Assignments/ass6: ./bank
ACCOUNT ID:    0 BALANCE: $    0.00
ACCOUNT ID:   10 BALANCE: $    0.00
```

main.c:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void main() {
        FILE* ssv = fopen("students.ssv", "rt");
        if (ssv == NULL) {
                printf("\n File opening failed");
                exit(1);
        }

        int acct = 0;
        float amnt = 0;

        char line [100], bankAcc[10], balChange[10];
        while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), ssv)) {
                parse(line,&acct, &amnt);
                findUpdate(acct, amnt);
        }
        prettyPrint();
}
```

linked.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct ACCOUNT {
        int accountNumber;
        float balance;
        struct ACCOUNT* next;
};

struct ACCOUNT* head = NULL;

void findUpdate(int account, float amount) {

        head = (struct ACCOUNT*)malloc(sizeof(struct ACCOUNT));

        if (head == NULL) exit (1);

        struct ACCOUNT* current = head;

        int changed = 0;

        while(current->next != NULL) {
                if (current->accountNumber == account) {
                        current->balance = current->balance + amount;
                changed++;
                }
        current = current->next;
        }

        if ((changed==0)&&(current->next==NULL)) {
        struct ACCOUNT* newAccount=(struct ACCOUNT*)malloc(sizeof(struct ACCOUNT));
                if (newAccount == NULL) exit(1);
                current->next=newAccount;
                newAccount->accountNumber = account;
                newAccount->balance = amount;
                newAccount->next = NULL;

        }
}

void prettyPrint() {
        struct ACCOUNT *current = head;
        while (current!=NULL) {
                printf("ACCOUNT ID: %4d BALANCE: $ %7.2f \n",current->accountNumber, current->balance);
                current = current->next;
        }
}
```

ssv.c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void parse(char record[], int *acct, float *amnt) {
        char *end;
        char acctarr[10], amntarr[10];
        sscanf (record, "%d %f", acct, amnt);
        return;
}
```

Example .ssv file

```
10 100.0 
20 -50.5 
10 -20.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1)** you are initializing your list each time you are trying to update ballance.
you should init it only when it points to NULL

```
if(head == NULL){
        head = (struct ACCOUNT*)malloc(sizeof(struct ACCOUNT));
        head->accountNumber = account;
        head->balance = 0;
}
```

**2)** Your while condition is ok for preservation of tail but wrong for accounting.
When you going through the list you are skipping last account but preserve tail.
You should change the way you preserve tail to process last entry in the list.
Here is an option to use your iterator for preservation of tail:

```
while(1){
    if (current->accountNumber == account) {
        current->balance = current->balance + amount;
        changed++;
    }
    if(current->next == NULL){
        break;
    }
    current = current->next;
}
```

and of course code is much more readable when you do not use the same variable for multiple purposes.

```
struct ACCOUNT* tail = head;
while(current){
  if (current->accountNumber == account) {
      current->balance = current->balance + amount;
      changed++;
  }
  tail = current;
  current = current->next;
}

if ((changed==0)&&(tail->next==NULL)) {
    struct ACCOUNT* newAccount=(struct ACCOUNT*)malloc(sizeof(struct ACCOUNT));
    tail->next=newAccount;
    newAccount->accountNumber = account;
    newAccount->balance = amount;
    newAccount->next = NULL;
}
```

Comment: While this has fixed the error of the header not containing any account, for some reason, the account balances are still refusing to update. I'm wondering if there is an error in the parse () function not returning the correct values?

Comment: Parsing is ok. Most likely you did not apply one of my patches properly.

Comment: I ran the code and the 0's are still showing up in the balance area for some reason, despite copying the code verbatim. I suspect it may have to do with the while loop or the new break. @maxim